# mysql does multiple inserts on one query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a command on a web page, which calls a controller class which executes a model function of inserting some data into a database, its pretty straight forward except everytime I press the button the data is being inserted three times instead of just once.

```
function run_no_submenu_job($job_name,$client_name,$server_id)
{
    $this->Jobmodel->insert_client_history($userID,$firstname,$lastname,$clientname,$data['time']);
}
```

and the model function looks like this:

```
$query=$this->db->query("INSERT INTO clientaccesshistory (jobid, clientid, firstname, lastname, clientname, menu, submenu, starttime) VALUES ('$time','$userID','$firstname','$lastname','$clientname','Monitor/Verify', '$this->job_name',current_timestamp() )");
```

When i look in the database the information has been added three times.  Sometimes the time stamp is 1 second apart, and sometimes not.  Sometimes this behaviour does not happen and it just inserts it once as expected.  Not sure if this is a connection with mysql since its on my local pc.

thanks

Comment: The code you posted would not cause three insertions. Please consider posting more of your code, especially relevant parts containing a loop.

Comment: This is all the code I'm using , the only loops are in the view to display the list of menu options (nothing to do with the mysql function call)

Answer (score 0):

Are you debouncing the button press? In other words, is the function being called on "Button Down" or on "Button Click"?

The difference is that a "Click" will only happen once, but depending on how long you take to click the button it will register as "Down" for multiple update cycles, thus calling the insert multiple times. If you don't have access to a mouse click event, try calling the function only when the button's value changes from up to down.

If the case above, the HTML would be

```
<input type="button" onClick=run_no_submenu_job>
```

You can't provide arguments to functions this way, however. It's been a long time since I used Javascript so I am unsure exactly how to solve your problem. Hopefully someone else can expand on this issue.

Comment: According to you, depending on how long the mouse button is pressed, that many inserts have to happen. In that case, the number of inserts everytime should be different and not exactly 3 all the time.

Comment: yes i believe this is the issue. Could you provide a solution to do this with javascript?  I'm just using the codeigniter anchor function which returns a <a href> link to the browswer: